# Induced monochromatic subtree in a graph which is colored by two colors

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

Suppose we have a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices. If we color the edges of $G$ by two colors, then we can conclude by Konig's Theorem that there exists a monochromatic subtree $T$ with at least $n/{\alpha}$ vertices, $\alpha$ is the size of  maximum independent set in the graph.

I was wondering if there is any theorem that I can conclude there exists an INDUCED monochromatic subtree, not just subtree?

Thanks in advance for any help/comment!

Comment: If you are looking for a bound that only depends on $\alpha$, then you cannot get much. For fixed $\alpha$, there are infinite classes of graphs with colorings whose largest monochromatic subtree has only $\alpha+1$ vertices.

Comment: @ Sean English; Actually, I am looking for a bound that depends on n, I used $\alpha$ in my question, because that was the only bound that I could get!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every connected $n$-vertex graph with $O(n)$ edges has an induced tree of size $2\log\log n+O(\log\log\log n)$ (I guess the constants in the $O$'s depend on each other); see

P. Erdős, M. Saks, and V. T. Sós. Maximum induced trees in graphs. J. Combinatorial Theory, Series B, 41(1):61 – 79, 1986. doi:10.1016/0095-8956(86)90028-6

Additionally, connected triangle-free graphs have induced trees of size $\sqrt n$ and connected clique-free graphs for larger clique sizes have logarithmic induced trees; see

J. Fox, P.-S. Loh, and B. Sudakov. Large induced trees in $K_r$-free graphs. J. Combinatorial Theory, Series B, 99(2):494 – 501, 2009. doi:10.1016/j.jctb.2008.10.001

So if you know something about the connectivity and subgraphs of the two colors then you can conclude something about the sizes of the monochromatic trees.